# C macro with one parameter with 3 trailing points (not variadic macro)

Tags: c, macros

I stumble on some piece of C code

```
#define OUTPUT_ABORT(_what, _status...) \
    do { \
        LOG(_what); \  
        abort(_status); \
    } while (0)
```

It is definitly not a variadic macro argument, but can't find here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace any explanation on the `...` after _status

This macro is called with only one parameter, so without _status parameter.

So my question :

- what is this syntax (looks like a default options.) ?
- can anyone point me to ressource explaining it.
- what is the default value in case the macro is called without the _status parameter being set ?

Comment: Is it used? Does it work? In which compiler?

Comment: it does compile with gcc 8.5.0
if it works , I would say this is not the point, if it `works on my machine` but it is UB, then it's still a bug..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a GCC extension

1. It allows to use a name other than `__VA_ARGS__`
2. It allows the variable arguments to be empty, even when named arguments are present

From [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html):

> If your macro is complicated, you may want a more descriptive name for the variable argument than __VA_ARGS__. CPP permits this, as an extension. You may write an argument name immediately before the ‘...’; that name is used for the variable argument. The eprintf macro above could be written `#define eprintf(args...) fprintf (stderr, args)` using this extension. You cannot use __VA_ARGS__ and this extension in the same macro.
>
> You can have named arguments as well as variable arguments in a
> variadic macro. We could define eprintf like this, instead: `#define eprintf(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__)` This formulation looks more descriptive, but historically it was less flexible: you had to supply at least one argument after the format string. In standard C, you could not omit the comma separating the named argument from the variable arguments.
>
> [...]
>
> Furthermore, if you left the variable argument empty, you would have
> gotten a syntax error, because there would have been an extra comma
> after the format string. [...] GNU CPP also has a pair of extensions
> which deal with this problem

Comment: This is probably a GNU C remain from the time before C99 introduced variadic macros. From that link: "Variadic macros became a standard part of the C language with C99. GNU CPP previously supported them with a named variable argument"